# When the Population is Itself a Sample -Which Statistics Formulae do you use?

Tags: statistics

I've started a statistics course after not having studied the subject before, so am very new to the topic. I've just been introduced to the formulae for expected value, variance, and standard deviation of a population and a sample, but am stuck with understanding the true difference between a population and a sample.

Now, I'm still working on understanding and memorising the formulae themselves, but one of the things I noticed was that there is a difference in the formulae of some functions based on whether you're working them out for a sample or a population, e.g. variance.

The first thing that occurred to me then is what if your population is itself effectively a sample of a broader population? E.g. if I were studying the heights of human adult women, I would take a sample from the women of my town, and (as I understand it) use the sample-formulae on that data - the set of all adult women in my town would be the 'population'. But then the women in my town are a sample of the greater population of all those women in my country, and those in turn would be a sample of all those on Earth. And the since the formulae for your data is different based on whether it's a sample or a population, wouldn't mislabeling your data set damage the accuracy of your work?

I'm guessing I've misunderstood the definition of the terms, but what is the trude difference between/definition of a sample and a population in this context? I'm sure it's a super easy to grasp idea but being new to it I found it confusing.

Many thanks indeed, really appreciate it.

Comment: When referring to population, you're describing a group that you want to conduct your study about. So if you're interested in the height of adult women in your town, all adult women in your town are considered the population. All adult women in the world is another population of which all adult women in your town are part of, but for the purposes of your study, you're only interested in adult women in your town, and so that is the population of interest. A sample would then be some group of the adult women in your town.

Comment: What is the difference between a formula for a sample and for the population?

Comment: A **random** sample is what the formulas assume?

Answer (score 0):

**Sample SD vs. poopulation SD.** The main difference you may see in formulas is that the sample standard deviation of
observations $X_1, X-2, \dots, X_n$ is 
$$S_X = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2}{n-1}}.$$

while the population distribution of numbers $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N$ is
$$\sigma_X = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N(X_i - \bar X)^2}{N}}.$$

**Notation.** Notice that Latin letters are often used for sample statistics and
Greek letters for population parameters.

**Finite population correction.** If your sample (without replacement) from a population of size $N$ does not
consist of more than about $n = N/10,$ then it is customary in most
applications to ignore that the population is getting "depleted" as
the sampling goes on so that the later observations are selected from
a smaller population. In case the sample consists of more than 10% of
the population, one usually uses a 'finite population correction' in
computing the standard deviation (or variance) of the sample. (You can
google that. In [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error), look under 'Effect of population size'.)

This means that a random sample for a public opinion poll in a local
school board election may be analyzed in much the same way as for a
nationwide poll about public agreement with congressional or parlementary
votes.

*Note:* In the US, it may be easier to conduct a nationwide poll than
a local one because phone banks in Nebraska (or somewhere in the middle
of the country) can work for a full day calling people at 'convenient'
times in different time zones as the day wears on. A local poll for
California may have to schedule phone banks in conjunction with another
one in New York in order to make efficient use of personnel. Without the finite population correction and for percentages near 1/2, the 95% margin of sampling error is often about $1/\sqrt{n},$ so, for example with about $n = 2500$
respondents, the margin of error is about $\pm2\%.$